# Google Maps For Work API in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I need to know how to call google maps API for work form inside a an ASP.NET C# code
namely the Geocoding API
I tried using this

```
        string query = "30.0013759" + "," + "31.236013";
        string address = "";
        XmlDocument geocoderXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        geocoderXmlDoc.Load("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?client=gme-myclientid&latlng=" + query + "&sensor=false");
```

but it responded with 403 forbidden to me
can anybody help?

Comment: Did you consult the Google maps API documentation? There is quite a lot covered there concerning error messages (including 403 - just checked)

Comment: just out of curiosity; is gme-myclientid beign replaced with a valid client id before sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this documentation regarding [403 error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#signature_403) for Google Maps Geocode. It says:

> Why am I receiving a HTTP 403 Forbidden response to my Maps API web service requests?
>   An HTTP 403 response indicates a permission issue, likely because the signature could not be verified for this request. This could be because:
>
> a. A signature has been specified but is incorrect for this request.
>
> b. The request specifies a Google Maps API for Work client id but does not specify a signature, and the web service being called requires that all requests made using a client id include a valid signature.
>
> c. A signature has been specified but the associated Google Maps API for Work client ID has not been specified.